# SwiftUI - Sheet shows Data half way down the sheet

Tags: swiftui, alignment, scrollview

I am building a small APP where I wanna present a Sheet when a Button is pressed, it all works fine, but when the Sheet is presented the Data starts half way down the Screen rather than at the Top. I am using a ScrollView in the Sheet and above the ScrollView I have a Text and an Image which is Static.

I tried pretty much everything I could find and think of without any success. So now I am hoping someone out there can help me with this.

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

Here is the start of the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PopupView: View {

    @State var painted = CGFloat(10)
    @State var unpainted = CGFloat(1)

    @State var sPainted = CGFloat(5)
    @State var sUnpainted = CGFloat(6)

var body: some View {
    Color.white
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        HStack {
            Text("T'IS IS STATIC HEADER TXT")
                .tracking(2)
                .foregroundColor(Color.euGray)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .padding(.leading, 100)
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
            Image("close")
                .frame(width: 35, height: 35, alignment: .trailing)
        }
    }.frame(width: 400, alignment: .topLeading)
    ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image("qr")
                .resizable()
                .clipped()
                .padding(.top)
                .frame(width: 320, height: 320, alignment: .center)
                .padding(.top, 5)
            Text("JOHN APPLESEED")
                .foregroundColor(Color.nameGray)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .font(Font.custom("Source Sans Pro" ,size: 27))
                .padding(.top, 10)
            Text("01.01.1976")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .fontWeight(.regular)
                .font(.system(size: 13))
        }.frame(width: 320)
```

Comment: What happens if you re,over the Color.white at the top?

Comment: seems like you are looking to set the background white. 
In that case you could try this: `ZStack {
            Color.white.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack { ...your code...} } }`

Comment: @jnpdx thanks that was it, was no need to even have that line. Maybe you can make that an answer so I can tick it and close the question. Thank you